# Unable to show contents of variable enclosed by div as inline in thickbox

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I am trying to put a variable 'htmlcontent' into a div element and refer to the divId to show on the thickbox, but I am unable to get it working.

Trial 1

```
<div id="htmlCont">
<p> $document.getElementById("htmlEditor").getElementsByTagName('html:textarea'); < p>
</div>
<a href="#TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId=htmlCont&modal=true" class="thickbox">showPreview1< /a>
```

Trial 2

```
<div id="htmlCont">
<input type="hidden" id="htmlCon" value= document.getElementById("htmlEditor").getElementsByTagName('html:textarea'); />
</div>
<a href="#TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId=htmlCont&modal=true" class="thickbox">showPreview2< /a>
```

Trial 3

```
<a href="#TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId=<% request.getHtmlEditpane().getvalue() %>&modal=true" class="thickbox">showPreview3< /a>
```

Comment: What's up with the weird spaces at the beginning of your tags?

Comment: @karim, possibly it's unfamiliarity with the SO mark-down? Incidentally, @prass, it's probably worth reading the [SO Mark-Down editing help pages for guidance on this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/). Also, are you *really* trying to put jQuery/JS directly into the (x)html? Please consider removing the JS to the head, or foot, of the document in the appropriate `<script></script>` blocks.

Comment: @David Thomas - but I don't see how that could result in the spaces. Maybe I should just keep my mouth shut...

Comment: I have added spaces just before posting here, becoz the html source was not showing up in the preview.

Comment: i have my js code an functions in scipt tags. whereas here i was trying to fetch the value needed into the dev element. Please correct my errors.

Comment: karim, thanks for providing the markdown help. this is first time for me to post a question.

Comment: @karim the unfamiliarity is a problem because typing `<div>` into the Mark-down editor without indenting it by four spaces, or surrounding it with back-ticks, either causes the content to be hidden (or creates literal html in the feedback area, which is stripped out/escaped, on actual posting). The space prevents the editor interpreting it *as* html. What can I say? I remember my first days and the confusion... XD

Comment: @david , i agree with you its just day one for prass , and it takes time to format the code , we should help people when they join , otherwise they may dislilke and go away.

Comment: @David - Now I feel like a total idiot. @prass, my apologies for my insensitivity. Welcome to SO! And sorry I had to be such an ass-hat.

Comment: @karim, no worries, I'm sure; we've all been there =)

Comment: @prass, okay; there are **questions:** where is the variable 'htmlcontent' coming from (`input`, element's `class` or `id`, or some other place)? Which `div`'s `id` do you want to get? And what do you want to **do** with it? Can you post your html mark-up?

Comment: I want to grab the content from a textarea which is enclosed by a div and pass it to the thickbox as inline

Comment: I am not sure if I can put the html here..

Comment: <td class="grid_main_cont" colspan="2">
  <div id="htmlEditor4" >
  <html:textarea name="createHeaderContentForm" property="htmlContent" cols="145" rows="21" styleId="htmlContent" styleClass="grid_main_cont" readonly="true" > </html:textarea>
  </div>
 </td>

Comment: <td class="grid_main_cont" align="right"> <a href="#TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId='htmlEditor4'&modal=true" class="thickbox">Preview1</a> <a href="#TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId=htmlEditor4.htmlContent&modal=true" class="thickbox">Preview2</a> <a href="#TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId=$('html:textarea','#htmlEditor4')&modal=true" class="thickbox">Preview3</a>

Comment: <div id="htmlCont">
  <p> $document.getElementById("htmlEditor4").getElementsByTagName('html:textarea'); <p>
  </div>
  <a href="#TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId=htmlCont&modal=true" class="thickbox">Preview3A</a> <div id="previewWindn">